# Slow dot product in R

Tags: r, performance, matrix, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

I am trying to take the dot product from a 331x23152 and 23152x23152 matrix.

In Python and Octave this is a trivial operation, but in R this seems to be incredibly slow.

```
N <- 331
M <- 23152

mat_1 = matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), N, M) 
mat_2 = matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), M, M) 
tm3 <- system.time({
    mat_3 = mat_1%*%mat_2
})
print(tm3)
```

The output is

```
user  system elapsed 
101.95    0.04  101.99
```

In other words, this dot product takes over 100 seconds to execute.

I am running R-3.4.0 64-bit, with RStudio v1.0.143 on a i7-4790 with 16 GB RAM. As such, I did not expect this operation to take so long.

Am I overlooking something? I have started looking into the packages bigmemory and bigalgebra, but I can't help but think there's a solution without having to resort to packages.

---

**EDIT**

To give you an idea of time difference, here's a script for Octave:

```
n = 331;
m = 23152;

mat_1 = rand(n,m);
mat_2 = rand(m,m);
tic
mat_3 = mat_1*mat_2;
toc
```

The output is

```
Elapsed time is 3.81038 seconds.
```

And in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import time

n = 331
m = 23152

mat_1 = np.random.random((n,m))
mat_2 = np.random.random((m,m))
tm_1 = time.time()
mat_3 = np.dot(mat_1,mat_2)
tm_2 = time.time()
tm_3 = tm_2 - tm_1
print(tm_3)
```

The output is

```
2.781277894973755
```

As you can see, these numbers are not even in the same ballpark.

**EDIT 2**

At Zheyuan Li's request, here are toy examples for dot products.

In R:

```
mat_1 = matrix(c(1,2,1,2,1,2), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
mat_2 = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
mat_3 = mat_1 %*% mat_2
print(mat_3)
```

The output is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    6    9
[2,]    6   12   18
```

In Octave:

```
mat_1 = [1,1,1;2,2,2];
mat_2 = [1,2,3;1,2,3;1,2,3];
mat_3 = mat_1*mat_2
```

The output is:

```
mat_3 =

    3    6    9
    6   12   18
```

In Python:

```
import numpy as np

mat_1 = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])
mat_2 = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
mat_3 = np.dot(mat_1, mat_2)
print(mat_3)
```

The output is:

```
[[ 3  6  9]
 [ 6 12 18]]
```

For more information on matrix dot products: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

**EDIT 3**

The output for `sessionInfo()` is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0
```

**EDIT 4**

I tried the `bigalgebra` package but this did not seem to speed things up:

```
library('bigalgebra')

N <- 331
M <- 23152

mat_1 = matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), N, M)
mat_1 <- as.big.matrix(mat_1)
mat_2 = matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), M, M)
tm3 <- system.time({
    mat_3 = mat_1%*%mat_2
})
print(tm3)
```

The output is:

```
   user  system elapsed 
 101.79    0.00  101.81
```

**EDIT 5**

James suggested to alter my randomly generated matrix:

```
N <- 331
M <- 23152

mat_1 = matrix( runif(N*M), N, M)
mat_2 = matrix( runif(M*M), M, M)
tm3 <- system.time({
    mat_3 = mat_1%*%mat_2
})
print(tm3)
```

The output is:

```
   user  system elapsed 
 102.46    0.05  103.00
```

Comment: The speed of R's matrix operations depends on your R version, OS, and whether it has the BLAS libraries linked in. One easy way is to install Microsoft R Open, or you can hook it up to [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mkl-with-r). [See here for more](https://simplystatistics.org/2016/01/21/parallel-blas-in-r/).

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi: If you mean do I want to take the dot product, then yes? As far as I know, all three implementations take the dot product from two matrices, or am I missing something?

Comment: With 8 cores: R: 4 to 5 cores, Python: 7 to 8 cores, Octave: 8 cores. So indeed it seems R is using about half of the available processing power

Comment: Octave `rand` and numpy `random` both produce values in a limited range: (0,1) and [0,1) respectively. You are using `rnorm` in R which draws from a normal distribution (that has infinite support) rather than `runif` which is the equivalent operation to what you are comparing to. When the matrix values are non-negative and bounded, there may be optimizations that the BLAS can make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off the replies from knb and Zheyuan Li, I started investigating optimized BLAS packages. I came across GotoBlas, OpenBLAS, and MKL, e.g. [here](http://blog.nguyenvq.com/blog/2014/11/10/optimized-r-and-python-standard-blas-vs-atlas-vs-openblas-vs-mkl/).

My conclusion is that MKL should outperform default BLAS by far.

It seems R has to be built from source in order to incorporate MKL. Instead, I found [R Open](https://mran.microsoft.com/open/). This has MKL (optionally) built-in, so installing is a breeze.

With the following code:

```
N <- 331
M <- 23152

mat_1 = matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), N, M)
mat_2 = matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), M, M)
tm3 <- system.time({
    mat_3 = mat_1%*%mat_2
})
print(tm3)
```

The output is:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  10.61    0.10    3.12
```

As such, one solution to this problem is to use MKL instead of default BLAS.

However, upon investigation my real life matrices are highly sparse. I was able to take advantage of that fact by using the `Matrix` package. In practice I used it like e.g. `Matrix(x = mat_1, sparse = TRUE)`, where `mat_1` would be a highly sparse matrix. This brought down the execution time to around 3 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

This is a trivial operation?? Matrix multiplication is always an expensive operation in linear algebra computations.

Actually I think it is quite fast. A matrix multiplication at this size has

```
2 * 23.152 * 23.152 * 0.331 = 354.8 GFLOP
```

With 100 seconds your performance is 3.5 GFLOPs. Note that on most machines, the performance is at most 0.8 GLOPs - 2 GFLOPs, unless you have an optimized BLAS library.

If you think implementation elsewhere is faster, check the possibility of usage of optimized BLAS, or parallel computing. R is doing this with a standard BLAS and no parallelism.

---

**Important**

From R-3.4.0, more tools are available with BLAS.

First of all, `sessionInfo()` now returns the **full path** of the linked BLAS library. Yes, this does not point to the symbolic link, but the final shared object! The other answer here just shows this: it has OpenBLAS.

The timing result (in the other answer) implies that parallel computing (via multi-threading in OpenBLAS) is in place. It is hard for me to tell the number of threads used, but looks like hyperthreading is on, as the slot for "system" is quite big!

Second, `options` can now set matrix multiplications methods, via `matprod`. Although this was introduced to deal with NA / NaN, it offers testing of performance, too!

- "internal" is an implementation in non-optimized triple loop nest. This is written in C, and has equal performance to the standard (reference) BLAS written in F77;
- "default", "blas" and "default.simd" mean using linked BLAS for computation, but the way for checking NA and NaN differs. If R is linked to standard BLAS, then as said, it has the same performance with "internal"; but otherwise we see significant boost. Also note that R team says that "default.simd" might be removed in future.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar machine: Linux PC, 16 GB RAM, intel 4770K ,

Relevant output from `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.15.1   clipr_0.3.2    tibble_1.3.0   colorout_1.1-2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0    Rcpp_0.12.10
```

On my machine, your code snippet takes ~5 seconds (started RStudio, created empty .R  file, ran snippet, output):

```
   user  system elapsed 
 27.608   5.524   4.920
```

Snippet:

```
N <- 331
M <- 23152

mat_1 = matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), N, M)
mat_2 = matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), M, M)
tm3 <- system.time({
        mat_3 = mat_1 %*% mat_2
})
print(tm3)
```